# Teamcity build, deploy and run nodejs application

Tags: javascript, node.js, teamcity, teamcity-8.0

I have a remote host on an ovh server that I can access with FTP and SSH.

I have a nodeJs backend that runs on this remote server.

I want to build, deploy and run this nodejs server on the remote host **from** TeamCity.

Actually, I can build the project with TeamCity and it works well, build passing or failing if I have wrong confirations.

**Question :**

How can I deploy and run my nodejs server , after the building steps, directly within teamcity ?

Thanks for advance

Answer (score 1):

1. You can create a teamcity remote agent on the target host that you can use to deploy the built code.
2. you can create a teamcity target that will ssh to the target host and deploy your artefacts generated in the build.

You can get the artefacts from build -> deploy either through teamcity artefacts or through mounted disk volumes(nfs disks)

Comment: Is this the standard way ? Do you have a link with more precisions ? Thanks for your help

Comment: This would be the standard way of doing it in teamcity. If you have a separate deploy tool, you can build and test artefats in teamcity and hook it to the deploy tool